# Snowflake Failed to cast variant value to DATE

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a pandas dataframe `df` that I want to add to a table in Snowflake. However when I run the code below I get a programming error saying that it failed to cast a value to date format.

```
import snowflake.connector
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import write_pandas

success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(cnn, df, "TABLE_NAME", quote_identifiers=False)

>>> ProgrammingError: 100071 (22000): Failed to cast variant value 1466467200000000 to DATE
```

A few things I tried:

1. I tried to pinpoint where this value is in my dataframe that's causing the erorr, but the commands below returned nothing, which is really strange! Also took a look at the original csv file, and didn't spot any format error.

```
df[df.eq("1466467200000000").any(1)]

df[df.eq(1466467200000000).any(1)]
```

2. Date columns are already parsed, and when I print `df.dtypes`, the date columns are in the correct `datetime64[ns]` type.
3. I tried running the code below to parse the date columns once again, coercing any errors - but this did not make any difference.

```
df['date_col']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'],errors='coerce')
```

Any ideas what might be causing the error? Any help or advice will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Will it work if you create a new table with write_pandas? eg: ```success, nchunks, nrows, _ = write_pandas(cnn, df, table_name='TEST_NEW_TABLE', auto_create_table=True, table_type='temporary', overwrite=True, database='MY_DB', schema='MY_SCHEMA')```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the error appears because your target table expect to get the `DATE` type, which includes only YYYY-MM-DD part, while `datetime64[ns]` has the entire timestamp up to decimal seconds. If you want to have only the date in your target table in Snowflake, try extracting the date part from your timestamp before writing it to Snowflake:

```
df['date_col']=pd.to_datetime(df['date_col'],errors='coerce').dt.date
```

If you want to save the entire timestamp value, then use the target columns with the type, e.g. `TIMESTAMP`, then your code should work.